# ng-class condition changing but not applying new style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change the background of the`pane` of an Ionic app on condition of the `ng-class` as below. Manually changing the condition in the code and refreshing the served page works fine. Changing the condition from the input is not working.Since I'm using native angular directives I'm guessing the digest loop should run automatically? What could be the issue here?

```
<body ng-app="starter" >

    <ion-pane ng-controller= "CardsCtrl" ng-class = " 1 < {{hello || 0}} ?'background1':'background2'">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content  scroll = "false">
     <div class = "item item-input">
       <input type="number"  name="" placeholder="Do sometthing awesome Fitz!" ng-model = "hello">
     </div>

//Checking ng-model binding here
     {{hello}}


      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Comment: what is the value of `hello` ?

Comment: I'm just punching in random numbers into the input to toggle the state of the condition between true and false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide an expression which represents an object, array, or string or you can provide and object or array directly to `ngClass`.

It looks like you would want to use an object.

Here is an object when `hello` is greater than 0 the class "background1" will be applied, when `hello` is less than or equal to 0, "background2" will be applied

```
ng-class="{background1: hello > 0, background2: hello <= 0}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

> `ng-class = " 1 < {{hello || 0}} ?'background1':'background2'"

to

`ng-class=" 1 < hello || 0 ?'background1':'background2'"`

You don't need to use `{{}}` interpolation operators in here.

Comment: We are all sub-amateurs here.